# For the Vault Cards' Manufacturer-related challenges, grenades don't count?

Tags: borderlands-3

For the Vault Cards' Manufacturer-related challenges, grenades don't count?

I have a "Kill 250 enemies with Hyperion weapons", and while my Widowmaker grenade mod counts for the Galaxy Manufacturers' Challenge of Business Bombadier: "Kill enemies with Hyperion grenades."

They don't seem to be counting for the Vault Card? Or is it because Widowmaker's a strange one? It has multiple different possible manufacturers, and the initial grenade is not what kills?

I lob a mine, which, on explosion, turns into homing rockets?

I wonder if it's similar to how Zane's Duct Tape Mod is said to protect Zane from his own guns and grenades, but the Wiki [seems to indicate](https://borderlands.fandom.com/wiki/Duct_Tape_Mod#Notes) that's incorrect somehow?

Comment: I know this is quite late, but it looks like the wiki has updated. It originally specifically said that the grenades spawned by Duct Tape Mod would self-damage, and I haven't confirmed that yet, but I *can* confirm that (1) it definitely does protect from the direct damage, but (2) it absolutely does *not* protect from DoT caused by the same. Therefore, pure explosive weapons are actually the safest, whereas other elemental weapons can melt you with DoT alone. I'll try to verify another time on grenades spawned by the skill as well, though, and I'm unsure about the answer to the main question

Comment: @fyrepenguin - Good luck! I'm still wondering about this question now that you brought it up, since I've been playing other games, so still haven't finished this! :rofl